# implement for loop inside dropdown list razor view

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc, razor-pages

im trying to implement a dropdown list inside razor view with items from for loop .
i need the html results to  look like

```
<select name="budget">
            <option>--Please select --</option>
            <option>Not sure</option>
<option> 1000 - 2000</option>
<option> ...</option>
 <option>above 11000</option>
```

my code look like this :

```
 <select name = "budget" >
            <option>--Please select --</option>
            <option>Not sure</option>
            @for (int j = 1000; j < 11000; j += 1000)
            {
                <option>
                    @{
                        ("{{0}} -{{1}}", j, j + 1000);
                    }
                </option>
            }
            <option>above 11000</option>
        </select>
```

And the error im getting is: `"Only assignment, call, increment, decrement, await, and new object expressions can be used as a statement`
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try it:

```
 <select name = "budget" >
        <option>--Please select --</option>
        <option>Not sure</option>
        @for (int j = 1000; j < 11000; j += 1000)
        {
            <option>
                @($"{j} -{j + 1000}" )
            </option>
        }
        <option>above 11000</option>
    </select>
```